# Error evaluating Simulation in playground

Tags: plutus, plutus-playground, error

I was finally able to run the playground and I was following exactly what the instructor was saying on the video, adding the wallets and actions but only the genesis transaction shows up when I evaluate it at the end

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 1):

This is a minutxo failure. Likely wallet 1 doesn't have enough Lovelace in the initial genesis for holding the minted NFT. Try assigning at least 2000000 (2 Ada) to that wallet.